# GLIE MC control (reinforcement learning): how the policy affects evaluation?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, monte-carlo-methods

In his lecture 5 of the course "Reinforcement Learning", David Silver introduced GLIE Monte-Carlo Control.

[image]

I understand that we do policy evaluation for one step and then policy improvement. My question is how does the improved policy come into play in this GLIE algorithm?

Is `Gt` (return) based on the policy somehow? is that where the new policy comes in?
Asked another way, how are policy evaluation and policy improvement connected in this image?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE! I just want to let you know that you case use latex on this site, so you may want to format your math symbols it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy is used in determining the next sequence of state-action pairs in the next episode. This means that the policy is determining indirectly the next `Gt`